# Echo every third Thursday starting 3 March 2016

Tags: php, wordpress

Im developing a website for a company using wordpress

They have a board meeting every 3rd Thursday starting 3 March 2016

Im trying to create a shortcode

I want to echo when the next meeting will occur.

This is what ive got so far, but that just isnt correct.

```
// ECHO next board_meeting - Use [next_board_meeting]
add_shortcode( 'next_board_meeting', 'next_board_meeting_shortcode' );
function next_board_meeting_shortcode( $str ) {

echo date_i18n('l j F', strtotime('next thursday +2 week'));

}
```

I've been searching the web for something like this , but here I am, asking for your help.

Is there a simple way to do this , or do I need to create a complex php script ?

Bear in mind, I just learned how to do simple tasks in php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will get you third Thursday of current month ..

If the current date has passed the 3rd Thurs then It will show 3rd Thurs of next month.. If current Month is December and has passed  3rd Thurs then it will show 3rd Thurs in next year in Jan

```
<?php
$current_date = strtotime(date("d.m.Y"));

//$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));

$FullMonth = date('F',$current_date);
$FullYear = date('Y',$current_date);
$Third_Thus = date('d F Y', strtotime('third thursday of '.$FullMonth.' '.$FullYear));
$ThirdThus_tmstamp = strtotime($Third_Thus);
if($current_date <= $ThirdThus_tmstamp){
    echo date('d F Y', strtotime('third thursday of '.$FullMonth.' '.$FullYear));
}
else{
    if($FullMonth != 'December'){
        $FullMonth = date('F',strtotime("+1 month", $current_date));
        $FullYear = date('Y',$current_date);
    } else{
        $Next_Year = strtotime("+1 year", $current_date);
        $FullYear = date('Y',$Next_Year);
        $FullMonth = date('F',strtotime("+1 month", $Next_Year));
    }
    echo date('d F Y', strtotime('third thursday of '.$FullMonth.' '.$FullYear));
}?>
```

> This will show only one 3rd Thurs of either Current Month or Next
>   Month depending on the current date.. If you want the 3rd Thurs of
>   next 2-3 month then you can make some changes I guess now !!!

Comment: pls accept the answer if it satisfies your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that only shows the current month. They have a board meeting every 3rd thursday. So I dont think it will get the next months meeting if today is after this months meeting. For example : in May the meeting will occur on the 5th. And if today is 28 of April then it will not get May's next meeting.   Again , thank you for your reply , but I beleve that it will not work.

Comment: pls see the edited answer.. If the current date has passed the 3rd Thus then It will show 3rd sat of next month.. if Month skipping the date is Dec then It will show 3rd Thurs in Jan next Year

Comment: This works perfectly... I would never have been able to come up with this code on my own. I only modified one thing and that was _i18n after echo date..... And I guess if I wanted to change it to the second thursday of the month , I would just change third to second :-)

Thank you Very very much for this code :-) Best Regards

Comment: Can I ask for a bit of description on what you are doing with the else if ? I see you include december , is that to show the meeting in january if today is past meeting day in december ?

Comment: Yes.  I have provided explanation above

Comment: thank you.. it was a headache , but amazing code to learn @babiozk

Answer (score 0):

Should work with this simple shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'next_board_meeting', 'next_board_meeting_shortcode' );

function next_board_meeting_shortcode( $str ) {

  if(strtotime("3 thursday", strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00'))) > time())
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("3 thursday", strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00'))));
  else
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("3 thursday", strtotime("next month", strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00')))));

}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/530446

Comment: Im sorry, this will only echo the date after 3 tuesday's... What if the visitor is viewing the site the day before the meeting ? will it show the date for tomorrow ? and what if the visitor is viewing the site the day after the meeting . and the next meeting is in next month ,, will it show that date as well ?

Comment: thank you Aron, yes there was an error in the code. See the new edited example now - it will show the 3 thursday of the next month now, if it's the day after the meeting.